# How to do a redirect to another page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Hi I want to redirect out of CI project folder.

CI Dir : http://example.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/

Dir I want to redirect to :  http://example.net/folder1/folder2/

Here is my Function I'm using for redirection.

```
public function load_website(){

    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('http://example.net/folder1/folder2/','refresh');
}//
```

This function is not working and stays inside of CI dir.

Positive help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->output->set_header("Location:Enter Path");
```

Comment: Thanks for help, There was a typo. Anyhow your code worked too so i'm gonna mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect will refrech content because it stimulate a new call
So I think you need to do:

```
redirect ('folder1/folder2');
```